# Removes the first occurrence of every element that appears more than once in the linkedlist

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

Write the method removeFirst, member of class LinkedList, that removes the first occurrence of every element that appears more than once in the list. Do not use any auxiliary data structures and do not call any methods. The method signature is public void removeFirst().

Example 4.1. If the list contains: B => A => A => R => C => A => C => R, then
after calling removeFirst, its content becomes B => A => A => C => R.

I solved it as a member of class Arraylist and I used auxiliary data structures.

```
public void removeFirst() {

Node<T> traverse = head;

        int[] array = new int[10];
        int[] repeat = new int[10];
        int count=0;
        int rcount=0;

        boolean isAlready = false;

        while (traverse!=null)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                if (array[i]==traverse.value)
                {
                    isAlready=true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!isAlready)
                array[count++] = traverse.value;
            else
                repeat[rcount++] = traverse.value;

            traverse = traverse.next;
        }

        traverse= head;
        while (traverse!=null)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<rcount; i++)

            traverse=traverse.next;
        }

    }//
```

any idea how this can be solved as member of likedlist class without using any auxiliary data structure and all you can use is the

```
public class Node<T> {
public T data;
public Node<T> next;
public Node () {
data = null;
next = null;
}
public Node (T val) {
data = val;
next = null;
}
// Setters/Getters...
}//End of class Node

public class LinkedList<T> { //LinkedList class
private Node<T> head;
private Node<T> current;
public LinkedList () {
head = current = null;
}
```

Comment: I know how to code and I don't want anyone to solve ,, I just want a hint .. my problem with this problem is if we have B => A => R  => A => C => A => C => R ..  for example if I find A more than one I will delete first occurrence ..then i go to the next element but as you see what I find A again and it occurs more than one !

Comment: store the occurrence of a value in an array, if it is already in the array, remove the first instance of it. You have the fundamentals there! If the first occurrence has been deleted for that value, isAlready needs to set as false. This will prevent it from being checked again and we can move on to the next values.

Comment: @EvanBechtol are those arrays considered "auxiliary data structures"?

Comment: @ryanyuyu If they are, then your current setup won't work either.

Comment: Thank you Evan for your response , we can't make a new array but I guess I will make Node <T> tmp then i will store the head inside and make while loop head.next()!= null and if find it occurs .. it will make head.next() = head and so on

Comment: @ryanyuyu yes it consider auxiliary data structures

Comment: Could you post your Node<T> code, please?

Comment: @JhonAlx I update the problem and I add Node class and LinkedList class .. check them above

Comment: it could be handled easier if you'd introduce a new property for the Node, something like willBeRemoved flag. (implementing removeFirst would be straightforward in this case without any "auxiliary data structures")

Comment: @harcos, how is adding a new property not introducting an auxiliary structure?

Comment: @dfeuer, if I'd think this is an answer for the question I'd have written it as an answer with the algorithm but as you can see I didn't (anyway what I wrote is not a new structure, just a new flag)

Answer (score 1):

I come across this problem while I was studying for Data Structure Course it's kinda hard but here is what I did.

```
public void removeFirst() {
    int counter = 0 ;
    Node<T> tmp = null ; 
    Node<T> comp = head ; 
    current = head ;
    Node<T> secHead = null ;
    Node<T> secCurr = null ; 
    boolean check = false ;
    boolean control = true ;
    while(current.next != null || current == null) {
        counter = 0 ; 
        comp = head ;
        while(comp.next != null) { // we iterate using node through original list to check for occurences 
            if(comp.data == current.data) {
                counter++;
            }

            comp = comp.next ; 
        }
        if(comp.data == current.data) {
            counter++;
        }
        tmp = current ;
        if(counter >= 2) { 
            check = false ;
            secCurr = secHead ;
            while(secCurr != null) { // check for deleting to avoid multiple deletes  

                if(tmp.data.equals(secCurr.data)) {
                    check = true ;
                    break ;
                }
                secCurr = secCurr.next ;
            }
            secCurr = secHead ;
            if(!check) { // deleting and adding to our secondary linkedlist to check it later :)
                remove();
                control = false ;
                Node<T> tmp2;
                if (secHead == null) {
                    secHead = new Node<T> (tmp.data);
                    secCurr = secHead ;
                }
                else {
                    tmp2 = secCurr.next;
                    secCurr.next = new Node<T> (tmp.data);
                    secCurr = secCurr.next;
                    secCurr.next = tmp2;
                }
            }


        }
        if(control) { // remove() increment the current this is for checking 
            current = current.next ;
        }
        control = true ;

    }
}
```

by using the properties of class node you can make secondary LinkedList but not using the class itself hence we never used auxiliary data structure. you need to know how the internal methods work specifically. read the code carefully : )

Answer (score 1):

I started by taking the elements in reverse order and saw if there were repeated elements on the right side and then checked from the left side.

The only case you need to delete is when the repeated elements are on the right side only.

At the end of the code, I made one case to check the head element.

```
    public void removeFirst() {
    Node<T> c=head;
    Node<T> b;
    Node<T> q;
    int size=0;
    

    while(c!=null) { //Counting the size of the list 
        size++;
        c=c.next;
    }

    
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {//Going through the list 
        c=head;
        
        for(int j=0;j<size-i-1;j++) //Getting the elements in reverse order
            c=c.next;
        
        if(c.next!=null) {
            b=c.next;
            while(b!=null) {
                
                if(c.getData().equals(b.getData())){     //Check repeated elements on the right side
                    q=head;
                    while(q.next!=c) {
                        if(q.getData().equals(c.getData()))//Check repeated elements on the left side 
                            break;
                        
                            
                        q=q.next;
                    }
                    if(!q.getData().equals(c.getData())) {//Deletion occurs when there are elements on the right side only.
                        q.next=c.next;
                        break;}
                                                
                }   
                b=b.next;   

            }       
        }
        

        
    }
    
    
    q=head;//We only needed to check the head once, so I separated the check from the loop.
    b=head.next;
        while(b!=null) {
            if(q.getData().equals(b.getData())&&size!=0) {
                head=head.next;
                break;}
            
            else
                b=b.next;       }
        
    
    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

    list.add("B"); list.add("A"); list.add("A"); list.add("R");
    list.add("C");list.add("A");list.add("C");list.add("R");

    for (String string : list) {
        if (Collections.frequency(list, string) > 1) {
            set.add(string);
        }
    }
    for (String string : set) {
        list.remove(string);
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```